# Inserting a range of rows at the end of a table with row().EntireRow.insert

Tags: excel, vba, database

I have two sheets, the master sheet that is where input data, and the slave sheet where I store the data. In the master sheet when I put the data in table I want to copy it over and send it to the slave sheet in the correct table format. In order to accomplish this I created a variable that will find the last row in the slave sheet as the table will be growing. The button I made copies the data from the table (this part works) and is supposed to be copied over to the new range.

```
Sub button_click1()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim ERow As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Mws As Worksheet
    Dim DSws As Worksheet

    Set Mws = Sheets("Master")
    Set DSws = Sheets("DayShift")

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = DSws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = DSws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Create range'
    lRow = lRow + 1
    ERow = lRow + 3
    'Message Box'
     MsgBox "Last Row: " & lRow & vbNewLine & _
            "Last Column: " & lCol & vbNewLine & _
            "Range: " & lRow & ":" & ERow
    'Copy data from table'
     Mws.Range("A2:I5").Copy DSws.Range("AlRow:IERow")

    'Inserting 3 Rows from 3
    'ActiveSheet.Rows("lRow:ERow").EntireRow.Insert'

End Sub
```

The error I get is in the EntireRow.insert function. I can't find anything online on how to create my own dynamic range. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only need the top-left cell of a destination. `Mws.Range("A2:I5").Copy DSws.Range("A" & lRow)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reshape the target area of a copy & paste. You only need the top-left cell of a destination.

```
...
Mws.Range("A2:I5").Copy DSws.Range("A" & lRow)
```

However, if you are direct transferring values by way of arrays (i.e. without the clipboard), you will need to reshape the target area to match the dimensions of the array.

```
dim arr as variant

arr = Mws.Range("A2:I5").value
DSws.Range("A" & lRow).resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr
```